# Can only find average of first column from csv, the other columns show 0

Tags: python

Got a csv list with only 2 rows of data, needed to find and show average of each of the 3 scores.

```
name tribe id Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4

Aang Normad N321B 89 67 54 78

Gyatso Omaticay O111C 54 78 65 54
```

Managed to print the avg of Score1, but Score2,3 and 4shows up as 0, not sure which part of the code is wrong. Will appreciate anyone who can point in the right direction

```
def display_element_average():
   with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    air_average= sum(float(row["Air"]) for row in reader) /2
    water_average= sum(float(row["Water"]) for row in reader) /2
    earth_average= sum(float(row["Earth"]) for row in reader) /2
    fire_average= sum(float(row["Fire"]) for row in reader) /2
    print("==============================")
    print("Display element average")
    print("==============================")
    print("{0:<6}{1:^8}{2:^7}{3:^7}".format("Air |","Water |","Earth |","Fire |"))            
    print("{0:^6}{1:^8}{2:^7}{3:^7}".format(air_average, water_average, earth_average, fire_average))               

def menu():
    print ("=================================================================")
    print ("Welcome to Avatar Element System")
    print ("=================================================================")
    print ("1: Display element average")
    print ("2: Display avatar top element")
    print ("0: Exit")
    choice= input ("Enter choice:")
    if (choice == "1"):
        display_element_average()
    elif (choice =="2"):
        display_avatar_top_elements()
    elif (choice =="0"):
        print ("=================================================================")
        print ("Thank you for using Avatar Element System")
        print ("=================================================================")        
        exit (0)

menu()
```

Comment: `reader` is a reader object which you can iterate over - not the actual rows of the csv. So you can't iterate through it multiple times, without reseting it to read from the start of the file again using `csvfile.seek(0)`.  Or you can read the csv to a dictionary or dataframe which is kept in memory, and then use it however many times you like

Comment: The keys used to access the row items (e.g. `row["Air"]`) don't match the header names in your example csv..

Comment: that was my bad, the score1, score2 etc were from another question previously, but i copied it over since their values are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first generator expression exhausts the reader object so the following expressions have nothing to iterate.

You can accumulate the values in a for loop then calc the average after the loop ends.

```
air, water, earth, fire = 0,0,0,0
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for count, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        air += float(row["Air"])
        water += float(row["Water"])
        earth += float(row["Earth"])
        fire += float(row["Fire"])
fireave= fire / count
earthave = earth / count
waterave = water / count
airave = air / count
```

Comment: can i ask what does the 1 in the row in enumerate does? Does it start reading for whatever in row[1]?

Comment: enumerate is a built-in function, the [docs are here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).